# Jwt bearer token can not access to the page, 404 error code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've created a simple application and will register and getAccess token with asp.net core Identity.

I can get accesstoken but when I try to call the endpoint I get 404 error code.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var appConfiguration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.AddDependencies(appConfiguration);


//JWT Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PracticalTestWriteDbContext>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

UserController.cs

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace PracticalTest.Endpoint.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    //For admin Only
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Admins")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IActionResult AdminEndPoint()
    {
        var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
        return Ok($"Hi you are an {currentUser.Role}");
    }

    private UserModel GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity != null)
        {
            var userClaims = identity.Claims;
            return new UserModel
            {
                UserName = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value,
                Role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

If I remove builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole> then my controller will work, but I need to get the user from usermanager, and then generate the token and use it in my UserController.

here is the get access token process:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("AccessToken")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AccessToken([FromBody] LoginCredential? credential)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || credential == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = "Login failed" });
        }

        var identityUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(credential.Email);
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(identityUser);
        if (identityUser == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = "Login failed" });
        }

        var result =
            _userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(identityUser, identityUser.PasswordHash,
                credential.Password);
        if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = "Login failed" });
        }
        var accessToken = GenerateToken(credential, roles.ToList());
        return Ok(new { AccessToken = accessToken });
    }

    private string GenerateToken(LoginCredential user,List<string> roles)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new (ClaimTypes.Email,user.Email)
        };
        claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            _config["Jwt:Audience"],
            claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
            signingCredentials: credentials);


        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    }
```

Comment: Which endpoints you're getting the 404 error?

Comment: 404 error means page not found, this is related with your route config or else. Please share the url and route endpoint config with us to continue troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and solved this problem by using;

**[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]**

If you don't want to use this, change your code with this;

```
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

I solved my problem with this. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This solution [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] helped me.